# threejs create multiple objects and target them individually

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have create a cube in 'three.js', but I want to create the same cube 3 times and then target them so they can be animated individually with 'Tweenmax'

I am new to three.js so any help would be appreciated

fiddle here: 
https://fiddle.jshell.net/2gr5cc9y/

Comment: I don't see any Tweenmax code in your Fiddle. Did you try at all to do something yourself? Stackoverflow is not a coding service...

Comment: I am not asking for the tweenmax code, I just need to know how to get 3 of the same cubes on the page and target each one individually.  So you would have for example 3 canvas elements with different id's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here in this updated Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/2gr5cc9y/1/) is an example on how to draw three cubes.

You can draw one cube and simply clone it twice:

```
var cube1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
var cube2 = cube1.clone();
var cube3 = cube1.clone();
```

As you can see in the fiddle you don not need three canvas elements to do this. You can add them to one scene on the same canvas.